# Rotate the contents of a window

Tags: interface, workflow

I am using a .blend file someone else made, and some contents of their properties window is rotated 90° to the left. This setting might be very convenient for people whose eyes are rotated 90° in their heads, but in my case it's making it difficult to work.

[image]

How do I make the contents look like this below image?

[image]

Comment: Answered whilst offering a comment solution. lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this, Rightclick beside the panel name and choose `Align Vertical` instead of Horizontal as shown below:

[image]

This will be the result:

[image]